# How can I get a radio attribute name by unqie ID with jQuery using regex?

Tags: jquery, ajax, regex

I have the following input elements:

```
<input name="option[100]" value="first" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
<input name="option[100]" value="second" type="radio" />
<input name="option[100]" value="third" type="radio"/>
```

I able to use

```
    myOption = $('input[name^=\'option\']:checked').val();
```

to get the value of the radio button.

However, I want to know the name id which **100**, how am I able to get it?

I would want to submit an ajax as an array as it like post a form

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'product/product/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: { product_id: product_id,  option: myOption },
            dataType: 'text',
```

The PHP get the POST need to like `$myOption[100]=first;`

Comment: `myOption_name = $('input[name^=\'option\']:checked').attr('name');
console.log(myOption_name.replace(/^option\[(\d+)]$/, "$1"));`, or `myOption_name.match(/\d+/)[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, why not you put on answer?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the element name using `attr('name')` and use a very simple regex - `/\d+/`:

```js
var myOption_name = $('input[name^=\'option\']:checked').attr('name');
console.log(myOption_name.match(/\d+/)[0]);
// or
// console.log(myOption_name.replace(/^option\[(\d+)]$/, "$1"));
// or
// console.log(myOption_name.match(/^option\[(\d+)]$/)[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="option[100]" value="first" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
<input name="option[100]" value="second" type="radio" />
<input name="option[100]" value="third" type="radio"/>
```

If you want to make sure the name follows your specific pattern you may use

```
/^option\[(\d+)]$/
```

And either use `match` or `replace` (see commented code in the snippet above).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `option\[` - a `option[` substring
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `]`  - a closing `]`
- `$` - end of string.